# How to append disable_funtions in .user.ini

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I am using Apache 2 and php-fpm(7.2.24). I am currently managing multiple virtualHosts, so I am using .user.ini to manage them. Now, I would like to add a "disable_functions" to a "user. ini" file (note:not lifting, but adding some restrictions), but I found it useless, I failed. This seems to be inconsistent with what is said on this page https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php：“PHP settings passed with php_value or php_flag will overwrite their previous value. Please note that defining disable_functions or disable_classes will not overwrite previously defined php.ini values, but will append the new value instead.”

What should I do